# What is axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't understand what is `axis` in this code. What if we don't off this

```
fig , ax = plt.subplots(6, 10)

for i,axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
   axi.imshow(negative_patches[500 * i], cmap='gray')
   axi.axis('off')
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation already?
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html

Answer (score 0):

The command `axis('off')` remove the *axis notation* from the image.

For better understanding two example code is given below, one with `axis('off')` command and one without it.

**Example without `axis('off')` command:**

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = random.random((5,5))
img = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
img.set_cmap('Blues')
#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The image created by this code is looks like this:
[image]

**Example with `axis('off')` command:**

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = random.random((5,5))
img = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
img.set_cmap('Blues')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The image created by this code is looks like this:
[image]